# Codeigniter Form Validation in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to validate a form submitted in a modal with the codeigniter formvalidation helper. Is it possible to just reload the modal with the errors showing up via codeigniter functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reload only modal (or any div) content, but you need to use AJAX for that. I recommend https://github.com/eldarion/eldarion-ajax/ library for AJAX in Bootstrap, it's well explained and works fine.

Another solution is to add javascript validation, which doesn't require any page reloading at all (you obviously have to keep server side validation on). jQuery validation plugin is nice solution for that.